# a list to store different lists

Tags: r, list

I want to create a list container to store a number of other different lists. My code looks like

```
temp = list()
list1 = list(a=1)
list2 = list(b=2)
list3 = list(c=c(1,2), d=c(4,5))
temp[1] = list1
temp[2] = list2
temp[3] = list3
```

Warning message:
In temp[3] = list3 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. It seems that all lists should have same length. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: `temp[[1]] = list1` will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with elements *in* lists, you use `[[]]` when you want to change the list itself, you use `[]`

```
temp = list()
list1 = list(a=1)
list2 = list(b=2)
list3 = list(c=c(1,2), d=c(4,5))
temp[[1]] = list1
temp[[2]] = list2
temp[[3]] = list3
```